# Use ReadableStream with Response to return HTML from fetch event of Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to return a stream for the `HTML` response in a service worker but the browser does not seem to be able to parse it (I'm using chrome for this test).

So, this one works (in the `fetch` event):

```js
event.respondWith(new Response("<h1>Yellow!</h1>", { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html" }}))
```

But when I use a `ReadableStream` it no longer renders in the browser:

```js
const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
        controller.enqueue("<h1>Yellow!</h1>")
        controller.close()
    }
})
event.respondWith(new Response(stream, { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html" }}))
```

It seems like maybe the browser doesn't understand that I'm sending it a stream. But I don't know what headers I would need to use so the above works.

Resources that I have used:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Examples

https://philipwalton.com/articles/smaller-html-payloads-with-service-workers/

**UPDATE**

[My question similar to this one but for asynchronous case.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62461511/632495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't work when you don't lock stream with [ReadableStream.getReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader)

Also when you pass `ReadableStream` to [`Response` ctor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response), the [Response.text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) method doesn't process the stream and it returns `toString()` of an object instead.

```js
const createStream = () => new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    controller.enqueue("<h1 style=\"background: yellow;\">Yellow!</h1>")
    controller.close()
  }
})

const firstStream = createStream().getReader();
const secondStream = createStream().getReader();

new Response(firstStream, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
      }
    })
  .text()
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text);
  });
    

secondStream.read()
  .then(({
    value
  }) => {

    return new Response(value, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
      }
    });

  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text);
  });
```

Comment: This solution works great for the simple case but once I add in asynchronous code it no longer works. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: The second case works well without asynchronous code but for asynchronous code it grabs the first `value` and then ends. The first solution just prints out the object name.

Comment: Could you show an example how you implement aynchronous code in this scenario?

Comment: I made a new question here for the asynchronous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461511/use-asynchronous-readablestream-with-response-to-return-html-from-fetch-event-of