# Use Asynchronous ReadableStream with Response to return HTML from fetch event of Service Worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

This question is similar to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457644/use-readablestream-with-response-to-return-html-from-fetch-event-of-service-work/62459039#62459039) but takes into account asynchronous nature inside the `ReadableStream`.

This is my test code now:

```js
const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start(c) {
        let i = 1
        const t = setInterval(test, 5e2)
        function test() {
            c.enqueue("<h1>Yellow!</h1>")
            if (i++ === 5) {
                clearInterval(t)
                c.close()
            }
        }
    }
})
event.respondWith(new Response(stream, {headers: {"content-type": "text/html"}}))
```

The above code is not rendered by the browser and I'm not sure why. [According to examples online](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Examples) it seems like it should work. But it doesn't appear to be reading any of the `enqueue` items.

Note in my other question the answer at least rendered the first response:

```js
const createStream = () => new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    controller.enqueue("<h1 style=\"background: yellow;\">Yellow!</h1>")
    controller.close()
  }
})

const secondStream = createStream().getReader();
secondStream.read()
  .then(({
    value
  }) => {

    return new Response(value, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/html"
      }
    });

  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(text => {
    console.log(text);
  });
```

Which seems to make sense as it is reading everything at once without regard to if the stream is finished.

Resources that I have used:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream#Examples

https://philipwalton.com/articles/smaller-html-payloads-with-service-workers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `stream` likes when you are putting `Uint8Array` in `controller.enqueue` method.

With the help of [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder/TextEncoder) your example works.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "Yellow", value: 'yellow'},
  {name: "Green", value: 'green'},
  {name: "Blue", value: 'blue'},
  {name: "Red", value: 'red'},
  {name: "Orange", value: 'orange'},
]

const encoder = new TextEncoder();

const stream = new ReadableStream({
    start(controller) {
        let i = 1
        const handle = setInterval(test, 5e2)
        function test() {
            const {name, value} = data[i - 1];
            controller.enqueue(encoder.encode(`<h1 style="color: ${value};">${name}!</h1>`))
            if (i++ === 5) {
                clearInterval(handle)
                controller.close()
            }
        }
    }
})

new Response(stream, {headers: {"content-type": "text/html"}})
  .text().then(text => {
    document.body.innerHTML = text;
  })
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. How did you figure it out that you needed to encode the string?

Comment: I copy pasted the example from mdn which creates `ReadableStream` from `fetch` result and `console.log`'d what's getting `enqueued`